# Crossfade with responsiveSlides.js

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using [ResponsiveSlides.js](http://responsiveslides.com) and would like the slides to crossfade instead of fadeOut and fadeIn. Does someone know how to do it. It is using css3 with a query fallback. Here is the code of the script:

```
// Fading animation
slideTo = function (idx) {
    settings.before(idx);
    // If CSS3 transitions are supported
    if (supportsTransitions) {
        $slide
          .removeClass(visibleClass)
          .css(hidden)
          .eq(idx)
          .addClass(visibleClass)
          .css(visible);
        index = idx;
        setTimeout(function () {
            settings.after(idx);
        }, fadeTime);
      // If not, use jQuery fallback
    } else {
        $slide
          .stop()
          .fadeOut(fadeTime, function () {
            $(this)
              .removeClass(visibleClass)
              .css(hidden)
              .css("opacity", 1);
          })
          .eq(idx)
          .fadeIn(fadeTime, function () {
            $(this)
              .addClass(visibleClass)
              .css(visible);
            settings.after(idx);
            index = idx;
          });
      }
};
```

Comment: post your code on http://jsFiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wd7Jz/

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough: the fiddle is not just some place to drop code, like pastebin.com, it is a running demo to reproduce your problem. Your fiddle does nothing because it has no HTML... you should tune it until it reproduces, with fake (read: obfuscated) names, data and code, your real problem, so that we can start from that.

Comment: If you want to get an answer you should really put together a working fiddle showing your problem.

Comment: Wild guess here, but isn't there a "queue:false" to put on somewhere just like regular animations via jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

They *are* cross-fading in the default demo on http://responsiveslides.com/
See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: But it does not work. I have nothing changed to the code. How can i activate the crossfade?

Comment: Did you validate the page, and check the error console? Else, can you add a link to where you're using it? PS On the demo page, crossfade is activated by default.  `$(".rslides1").responsiveSlides({
        speed: 1000,
        maxwidth: 800
      });`

Comment: no errors in the console. i will add a video tomorrow to show you the fade.

Comment: Video won't help, you should rather post your code or a link. My guess is that something is wrong with your surroundings, not with the plugin. Above, you posted a snippet from the plugin's code, which is public anyway. I can't see what for. Also don't forget to try html5.validator.nu, which often helps. Make the page as valid as possible, so you can rule out unclosed tags etc.

Comment: I will check again with the html5.validator and write if there are no errors left. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Use a custom easing function so that they overlap enough to cover the background!

Use this: 
`visible = {"float": "left", "position": "relative", "opacity": 1, "zIndex": 2, 
        "-webkit-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275)",
            "transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275)"},
        hidden = {"float": "none", "position": "absolute", "opacity": 0, "zIndex": 1, 
        "-webkit-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045)",
            "transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045)"} ,`

to replace this:  
`visible = {"float": "left", "position": "relative", "opacity": 1, "zIndex": 2},
hidden = {"float": "none", "position": "absolute", "opacity": 0, "zIndex": 1},`